# What are the differences between user logical memory and virtual memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

Can some one point out the differences between user logical memory and virtual memory.An example would be really helpful.Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some context for your question ? I.e. where you encountered the terms.

Comment: Logical address generated by CPU is also referred to as Virtual address.

Comment: @cnicutar I was going through the material on the virtual memory where I found this particular statement:Virtual memory–separation of user logical memory from physical memory.I don't understand what does it refer to.

Comment: @SunEric Yes.Logical address are referred to Virtual address.But logical memory and virtual memory are different from Logical address and logical address. Aren't they?I think the the virtual memory is referred to the secondary memory such as hard disk,tapes etc..

Comment: @user1632141 You are right, Virtual memory combines active RAM and inactive memory on Direct Access Storage Device to form a large range of contiguous addresses(Source Wiki). Check this link, [http://superuser.com/questions/319000/what-differences-and-relations-are-between-logical-and-virtual-memory]. Hope it is usefull.

Comment: @cnicutar did you think you could have replied to the question even if he provided you with the context or were you just trying to annoy him??

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava I was not trying to annoy anybody. I genuinely felt more context was required.

Answer (score 2):

As far as user is concerned, all his logical memory is virtual. Virtual memory is an infrastructure that allows to address more memory than the amount of physical memory (RAM) existing on the machine. This is possible because even though a program might require large amount of memory, at any given moment the memory being addressed is limited. Memory manager pages the unused memory out to disk, freeing the physical memory. Whenever the paged out memory is needed, the memory manager accesses the disk and loads the block back to physical memory, allowing the user process to use it.